# Crystal Report SP26 SetDataSource() Method failed in computers of clients in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2019

​I'm working on Visual Studio 2019 and Crystal Report Service Pack 26. My code read data into ADO.NET dataset and I set those datases as datasourse of my reports. something like this in Visual Basic.Net:

```
    Dim ds1 As New DataSet1()

    Dim myRep As New CrystalReport1
    taAccArticleFields_TBL.Fill(ds1.AccArticleFields_TBL)
    myRep.SetDataSource(ds1)
    crvReport.ReportSource = myRep
```

When I run program through VS all is good and reports show without error. But when I want to run my program on another computer which only has CR26 runtime installed, it gives an error on calling SetDataSource method for report as below:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800002CD): Error in File temp_04020c6d-5b84-40d9-8558-bf87b6d5e554 4840_5464_{1C1D3ACF-9F25-45E2-B0EE-BB77F1DDA6B6}.rpt: Failed to load database information. 
at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.DatabaseControllerClass.ReplaceConnection(Object oldConnection, Object newConnection, Object parameterFields, Object crDBOptionUseDefault) 
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table.SetDataSource(Object val, Type type) 
at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.SetDataSourceInternal(Object val, Type type)
```

I encounter this with any program I write. Does anyone have idea to solve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks to @Julie I found missing file need to run ADO.Net report using Crystal Report SP26.
Unfortunately, When you install SP26 run-time it doesn't copy **crdb_adoplus.dll** file which need to Crystal Report to load data from ADO.Net dataset.

Here is the solution:

- **In 32bit operating systems:** you have to copy crdb_adoplus.dll file from developer computer to client machine from following folder:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86
- **In 64bit operating systems:** you have to copy crdb_adoplus.dll file from developer computer to client machine from following folder:

  C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64

  And it work correctly. I hope SAP resolve this problem in the future service pack.

Comment: Thank you so much for this, over 8 years later this solved a bug I'd been tearing my hair out over!

Comment: Thanks! This is an epic fail on SAP's part

Answer (score 1):

Please check in the [previous article](https://apps.support.sap.com/sap/support/knowledge/public/en/1631283), witch may provide you with a solution:

1.Copy the file crdb_filesystem.dll from the development computer to the client computer

2.CRdb_filesystem.dll is in the following directory on the development computer:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win32_x86`

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue and found that by repairing the program in Windows 'Programs and Features' it automatically fixed the problem without the need to even restart the machine!

[image]

The idea came from the a discussion on a SAP answers page (https://answers.sap.com/questions/12937477/sp26-and-installation.html) where it was said that -

> "the only thing that will help is to reinstall or repair."

It seems to be correct, I just wish I hadn't wasted ages trying to find an answer!

Comment: Repairing Sap Crystal Report  does not work in my case. I've tried all solutions in sap.com, but only copying file manually work for me.