# Connect Crystal Report with DataSet

Tags: asp.net-core, c#, mysql, database, crystal-reports

I have a problem when I want to connect Crystal Report with DataSet in c#.

> **Error**
>
> failed to load database information, details: unable to load database connector 'crdb_adoplus.dll'. the correct version of the database client for this type of database may not be installed.

Here's a [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic4sX.png)

Can you help me please?

Comment: the erreur in english : failed to load database information,
details: unable to load database connector 'crdb_adoplus.dll'. the correct version of the database client for this type of database may not be installed

Comment: This feels like a problem you should seek help with from SAP Crystal Reports, rather than Stack Overflow: https://www.crystalreports.com/faq/#lp-pom-block-1023

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem on Microsoft Visual studio 2019 by installing SP26 "*SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework (64-bit)*" *before "SAP Crystal Reports, version for Microsoft Studio*".

The main problem is that the run-time engine doesn't copy crdb_adoplus.dll file which need to Crystal Report to load data from ADO.Net dataset.

If you also followed my installation sequence, you must:

1. Remove "SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework (XX-bit)" and "SAP Crystal Reports, version for Microsoft Studio" by the control panel.
2. Run the "SAP Crystal Reports, version for Microsoft Studio" installer as Administrator. After the installation, it will automatically ask you to install the correct engine.

See also:
[Crystal Report SP26 SetDataSource() Method failed in computers of clients in Visual Studio 2019](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59666654/crystal-report-sp26-setdatasource-method-failed-in-computers-of-clients-in-vis)

Answer (score 3):

We are using Crystal Report's on 20+ server and we always install x32 and x64bit version.Today i installed SP30 from here for VS2019 https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/download-crystal-reports-for-visual-studio-2019/ , also today i tried to add a field to dataset and gave me 'crdb_adoplus.dll' error. After a lot of search, i installed x32 bit runtime both x64bit, it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
I uninstalled all crystal reports (for visual studio and runtime) and install only the version for Visual Studio and installed the runtime checking the last checkbox on the installation wizard (to install the correct runtime).

I think that when installing on top of an existing crystal some files are missing.